# Why does it not update on the website?

Tags: javascript, date, time

This code show time and date, but does not update it?
So it shows for example : 03:04 - but 1 min later it shows the same.

```
var language = window.navigator.language;
if (language.length > 2) {
    language = language.split('-');
    language = language[0];
}

//language = "fr"; // manually set language

if (language === "en") {
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
} else if (language === "cz") {
    var weekday = ["NedÄ›le", "PondÄ›lÃ­", "ÃšterÃ½", "StÅ™eda", "ÄŒtvrtek", "PÃ¡tek", "Sobota"];
    var month = ["Leden", "Ãšnor", "BÅ™ezen", "Duben", "KvÄ›ten", "ÄŒerven", "ÄŒervenec", "Srpen", "ZÃ¡Å™Ã­", "Å˜Ã­jen", "Listopad", "Prosinec"];
} else if (language === "it") {
    var weekday = ['Domenica', 'Luned&#236', 'Marted&#236', 'Mercoled&#236', 'Gioved&#236', 'Venerd&#236', 'Sabato'];
    var month = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"];
} else if (language === "sp") {
    var weekday = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "MiÃ©rcoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "SÃ¡bado"];
    var month = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
} else if (language === "de") {
    var weekday = ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag"];
    var month = ["Januar", "Februar", "MÃ¤rz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Ju li", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dez ember"];
} else if (language === "fr") {
    var weekday = ["Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi"];
    var month = ["Janvie", "FÃ©vrier", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "AoÃ»t", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "DÃ©cembre"];

} else if (language === "zh") {
    var weekday = ['æ˜ŸæœŸæ—¥', 'æ˜ŸæœŸä¸€', 'æ˜ŸæœŸäºŒ', 'æ˜ŸæœŸä¸‰', 'æ˜ŸæœŸå››', 'æ˜ŸæœŸäº”', 'æ˜ŸæœŸå…­'];
    var month = ['ä¸€æœˆ', 'äºŒæœˆ', 'ä¸‰æœˆ', 'å››æœˆ', 'äº”æœˆ', 'å…­æœˆ', 'ä¸ƒæœˆ', 'å…«æœˆ', 'ä¹æœˆ', 'åæœˆ', 'åä¸€æœˆ', 'åäºŒæœˆ'];
} else {
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
}

(function clock() {
    "use strict";
    var adjDay, twentyfour, currentTime, currentHours, currentMinutes, mnth, day, oday, year, dat;
    twentyfour = false; ///set twentyfour here.
    adjDay = function (day, daynum) {
        var offset, doffset, left;
        switch (day.length) {
        case 6:
            offset = "0px";
            doffset = "1px";
            left = "-1px";
            break;
        case 7:
            offset = "0px";
            doffset = "0px";
            left = "-1px";
            break;
        case 8:
            offset = "2px";
            doffset = "0px";
            left = "-4px";
            break;
        case 9:
            offset = "3.5px";
            doffset = ".1px";
            left = "-6px";
            break;
        default:
            offset = "0px";
            doffset = "0px";
            left = "0px";
        }
        if (daynum === 1) {
            offset = "1px";
            left = "-2px";
        }
        if (daynum === 5) {
            doffset = "1.5px";
        }
        if (daynum === 6) {
            left = "-4px";
            offset = "2px";
            doffset = ".1px";
        }
        document.getElementById('year').style.letterSpacing = offset;
        document.getElementById('day').style.letterSpacing = doffset;
        document.getElementById('dates').style.left = left;
    };

    currentTime = new Date();
    currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
    mnth = currentTime.getMonth();
    dat = currentTime.getDate();
    day = currentTime.getDay();
    oday = (dat < 10 ? "0" : "") + dat;
    year = currentTime.getFullYear();

    if (!twentyfour) {
        currentHours = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
        currentHours = (currentHours === 0) ? 12 : currentHours;
    }

    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes;
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = weekday[day] + ", " + month[mnth] + " " + oday;


    adjDay(weekday[day], day);
    setTimeout(function () {
        clock();
    }, 30000);
}());
```

Comment: any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: Tested the core code (outputting to console rather than to DOM elements) and it all works fine - outputs every 30 seconds, every second time is repeated (naturally) - check the console for errors

Comment: Darn you for not using 24h clock and not providing Swedish language ^^. just kidding, I would love to see a 24h clock and in the language i have on my computer instead of being forced to read a date how you constructed it to be format. `04-05-2015` is it April or may? i don't know... the best way would be to present it in the way that would follow the users localized settings [with Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) you can get that! i want it to be `2015-04-05` and it should be April

Comment: @Endless—even if the Intl object is supported, hosts don't generally reveal "localized settings". The usual recommendation is to use an unambiguous format, such as 4 April 2015 or April 4 2015. 2015-04-05 should also be interpreted correctly. I do not understood why the peculiar US format is used at all. ;-)

Comment: true but at least it helps with localized language of month and days with both short and long version

Comment: thanks guys - work now ! - There was an error in the html script 
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Weitere Informationen]

I fogott to make a div with 'day' sorry guys